# Display value of Array

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I have this function :

```
$array = $um_followers->api->following( $currentid );
```

If I tried a var_dump :

```
var_dump($um_followers->api->following( $currentid ));
```

This is the result :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["user_id1"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["user_id1"]=> string(2) "44" } }
```

1) I want to display the data **1** and **44** in the same line

2) I want to display the data **1** and **44** in the same line with a coma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
echo implode(' ', array_column( $array,'user_id1')); 
echo implode(', ', array_column( $array,'user_id1')); // with comma
```

Comment: Thank you but I am using an older version of php

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: if you need to get values of 'user_id1' column only and using php version below 5.5 you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
`$newArray = array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['user_id1'];
}, $array);`

Answer (score 0):

well, something like this?

```
$array = array(
    array("user_id1" => 1),
    array("user_id1" => 44),
);

$line1 = "";
$line2 = "";
foreach($array as $smallArray){
    $line1 .= $smallArray['user_id1'].' ';
    $line2 .= $smallArray['user_id1'].', ';
} 
$line1 = substr($line1, 0, -1); //delete last ' '
$line2 = substr($line2, 0, -2); //delete last ', '

echo $line1.'<br>';
echo $line2.'<br>';
```

it will echo this:

```
1 44
1, 44
```